# referencing an unnamed javascript object in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I am referencing a JSON file through a web service. The file contains an unnamed object. How do I refer to the object?

I am referencing the file like any normal JSON file

```
<script src="http://somewebservice.com/object.json"></script>
```

object.json

```
{
    "one":1,"two":2,"three":{
        "one":1,"two":2
    }
}
```

Do I really need to use `JSON.parse()`? It's already in a JSON file format.

Comment: load that file through `jsonp` protocol

Comment: The point of `JSON.parse` is to convert a string of text in JSON format into a usable Javascript object or array. So if you're receiving your data as a string, then you need to do `var obj = JSON.parse(data)`.

Comment: It's not a string. It's a JSON file.

Comment: Depends on how you're loading "object.json". If it's through ajax, you'll need to parse it. If you're using `<script src="object.json"></script>`, go ahead and reference away.

Comment: **Show how you are loading the resource.**

Comment: @Mike McCaughan Yeah but what do I reference...the object is unnamed!

Comment: @daniella Well then, *there's* your problem.

Comment: @daniella A file is just a file. It's just text until it's read in by some program. At some point or another, that text is going to be interpreted as a string. Then either you or some other program interprets, or *parses*, that string into something useful. If you're asking how to *load* a JSON file, that's a different subject.

Comment: Your edit shows you're attempting to load that JSON like it's a script. That's not going to work. You need to either modify that file to be a Javascript file and assign that data to a variable or load that file in using something like [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX).

Comment: *"Do I really need to use JSON.parse()? It's already in a JSON file format."* Don't confuse JSON, a textual, *language-independent* data representation, with object literals, a syntax construct of JavaScript. `JSON.parse` should exactly be used when you want to convert JSON data into a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is format that uses human-readable **text** to transmit data objects, so if "referencing a JSON file through a web service" means you get it as `String` in HTTP response, then yes, you have to use `JSON.parse()` to get javascript object from the string.

Answer (score 0):

Loading your data using `<script src="http://somewebservice.com/object.json"></script>` will leave you with no handle to the loaded resource.

Either use [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or, if a cross-origin policy is place, load the resource using some ajax mechanism.

### Using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```
fetch("http: //somewebservice.com/object.json").then(function (res) {
    try {
        console.log(JSON.parse(res));
    }
}).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using AJAX to retrieve the remote file.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     var objects=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
     console.log(objects);
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "http://somewebservice.com/object.json", true);
xhttp.send();
```